# Why can't Rails find this custom .yml file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In applications.rb I added this:

```
SOME_CONFIG = = YAML.load_file(File.expand_path('../some_config.yml', __FILE__))
```

I placed the file in:

```
/some/folder/myapp/config/some_config.yml
```

Then when I run 'rails server' I get an error:

```
.. in 'initialize' : no such file or directory /some/folder/myapp/config/some_config.yml (Errno::ENDENT) .... 'open' .... 'load_file' ....
```

Is this a permissions issue?

Comment: Did you mean to have `= =` there?

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe this to be a permissions issue.

1) Double check your spelling to make sure there are no typos.
2) Try reading another file, and see if it works.
3) Try: `YAML.load_file(File.join(Rails.root, 'config', 'some_config.yml'))` (Your error message shows that the issue is not in expanding the filename, but you never know).
4) Can you access it from the console?

Comment: getting an error about 'join', can't convert nil to String (TypeError)

Comment: Seems like it doesn't recognize `Rails.root`. What version of rails are you running? If it's an older version try RAILS_ROOT instead

Answer (score 0):

```
my_data =  HashWithIndifferentAccess.new(   YAML.load(File.read(File.expand_path('../../some_file.yml', __FILE__)))   )
```

**now due to HashWithIndifferentAccess**, you can get data in any of the given below syntax

```
my_data[:some_key] or my_data['some_key']
```