# yml file exists but rails server and passenger complains that it doesn't

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yaml, config

I've been following the railscast #85 by Ryan Bates at [this link](http://railscasts.com/episodes/85-yaml-configuration-file/) regarding YAML config files and I've ran into a problem that I can't find an answer to. I am using Ruby 1.9.3p194 through RVM and Rails 3.2.6.

In my applications.rb, I have

```
require 'yaml'
APP_CONFIG = YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/config/config.yml")[Rails.env]
```

I put the following in /config/config.yml:

```
username: "userhere"
password: "pass"
```

When I try "rails s" it gives me an error

```
/opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/1.9.1/psych.rb:297:in `initialize': No such file or directory - /config/config.yml (Errno::ENOENT)
```

and when I try to load the page in Passenger, I get

```
Error message:
No such file or directory - /config/config.yml
Exception class:
Errno::ENOENT
```

I've tried the File.join line [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4236391/why-cant-rails-find-this-custom-yml-file) but I got the same error

```
'join', can't convert nil to String (TypeError)
```

When I searched for the answer, every single thread solved the issue of the yml file not found error by creating the file, but mine exists and it still gives me the error message. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Your Rails.root is returning nil, that's the real problem you need to troubleshoot.

Comment: When I move the APP_CONFIG line to the environment.rb, I get uninitialized constant Pixel8meRails::Application::APP_CONFIG (NameError). I get the same error when I move it into /config/initializers/load_config.rb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is here: [Why is my Rails.root nil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4240627/why-is-my-rails-root-nil)

The Application object does not exist yet, so `Rails.root` returns `nil`.  Try putting the YAML config stuff in an initializer, like RB recommends.

Comment: Another relevant SO post:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284602/variable-loaded-in-environment-rb-not-found-in-tests

Comment: Thanks for the hint - I tried putting into /config/initializers/load_config.rb and it still wouldn't load. I figured it's because I'm trying to use the constant for the mailer settings before it was loaded. I ended up having to put the require yaml and APP_CONFIG line in config.before_configuration in application.rb.